# Rewinding or resetting Parallel effect in Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml

How can I 'rewind' or force the parallel effect to play from the very beginning once it already started to play?

Code sample:

```
<mx:Parallel id="parallelEffect" repeatCount="0">
    <mx:Fade alphaTo="1" target="{someTarget}" startDelay="2000" />
    <mx:Fade alphaTo="1" target="{someOtherTarget}" startDelay="4000" />
    <mx:Fade alphaTo="1" target="{thirdTarget}" startDelay="6000" />
    <mx:Fade alphaTo="1" target="{fourthTarget}" startDelay="8000" />
    <mx:Fade alphaTo="1" target="{fifthTarget}" startDelay="10000" />
</mx:Parallel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the end() method to end the effect and then call play() to start it from the beginning.

```
parallelEffect.end();
parallelEffect.play();
```

In your case if you call end that will set all your targets alpha to 1. If you run that again by calling play() the transition will not appear to work since it will transition from alpha of 1 to 1 since you have not set the alphaFrom value. Set the alphaFrom value to 0 and see if that helps.

You can also try playing in reverse and then ending the reverse.

```
parallelEffect.play(null, true); // play in reverse
parallelEffect.end(); // end it immediately
parallelEffect.play(); // play again
```

Although I think something else may be going on.

Comment: But that won't work. It will interrupt the effect currently playing (one of parallel's children in this case), not the parallel effect itself.

Comment: The parallel effect controls the child effects. When you call end on that it will call end on the child effects. Then when you call play it will call play on the child effects as well. Can you describe in more detail what is happening and what you want to happen?

Comment: Ok, so, I start to play that parallel effect (`parallelEffect.play()`) and let's say he runs until its fourth child. I want to be able on a button click or whatever to start parallel effect play back from the first child. Right now, I have this fading 'sequence' and that's not a complete code, just an example. In one moment I cover those images with some other canvas. When I close that canvas, I want to see parallel effect playing from the child #1, like when I started it first time. With `end()` function that's not happening. Instead, the effect ends with current child and plays from there.

Comment: It sounds like a lot going on. You may need to restart a parent effect above the parallel. Not knowing what's going on I think you may be able to loop through the effect instances and end each one. Get the parallel effect and then get references to the instances. Then try to end those individually before calling play on main parallel.

Comment: Also, typically you want to add more information to the main post rather than comments if possible.